# Possible to do modal segue on tab bar button press?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar that works as normal. However, I'd like for one of the buttons to have a view controller pop up modally, which will hide the tab bar. When it resigns, the tab bar will re-appear. I've seen this in other apps but I'm at a loss how to accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: DId u subclass the tab bar ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you're saying to subclass the tab bar and if that index is selected, then pop it up modally?

Comment: yes. Present the view controller modally in didSelectItem: method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?

1. Make segue **between ViewControllers** in your storyboard. You should ctrl+drag from one ViewControllers to another.
2. In the UITabBarDelegate method tabBar:didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item, implement

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue identifier" sender:someObj];